# Better solution to find a cell in an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
var myArray = [
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"name1",
            "resource_uri":"/api/v1/product/1"
        },
        {
            "id":5,
            "name":"name2",
            "resource_uri":"/api/v1/product/5"
        }
]
```

Each row is identified by it's unique id. I am quite new to Javascript and was wondering what was the best solution to find a cell based on id.

For example, for the id:5; my function must return:

```
findCell(myTable, id=5);
// this function must return:
{
     "id":5,
     "name":"name2",
     "resource_uri":"/api/v1/product/5"
}
```

I'm quite afraid to do an ugly for loop... Maybe there is some built-in javascript function to perform such basic operations.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to be in an array? Why not store the ids as keys in an object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get index of object by its property in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176908/how-to-get-index-of-object-by-its-property-in-javascript)

Comment: The title is misleading. You are searching an object in an array by a property. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579678/jquery-how-to-find-an-object-by-attribute-in-an-array/15767679#15767679).

Comment: Thank @LucaFagioli, it's answer work very well and without Javascript. The solution with filter is not the best for me as my id are unique. Sadly I can't change the output and put id as keys, it would have been a lot more easier though.

Comment: @AlexGrs you can build a key => index map on the fly though...

Comment: @Alex Grs, I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a built-in function - [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I would use it like this:

```
findCells(table, property, value) {
   return table.filter(function (item) {
      return item[property] === value;
   });
}

findCells(myTable, "id", 5);
```

This is a bit modified version, of what you want: it can find all cells by the specified property name value.

**Edit:** using `for` loop to search the first occurence of the element is okay, actually:

```
findCell(table, id) {
   var result = null;
   for (var i = 0, cell = table[0], l = table.length; i < l; i++, cell = table[i]) {
      if (cell.id === id) {
         result = cell;
         break;
      }
   }
   return result;
}

findCell(myTable, 5);
```

Comment: Don't forget that this returns an array. You might want to check the length of the array and return either `null` or the element itself, if the property is unique.

Comment: The filter function is when you want to filter an array. It will loop through all its values, it won't return when it finds what you are searching for.

Comment: @LucaFagioli as I said, it is a slightly modified version to find any amount of cells by any property passed as a parameter. In my opinion it is more useful, than simply finding first element by `id`.

Comment: An **id** should be unique, so it is a wrong approach searching for two or more different objects with the same **id**.

Comment: @LucaFagioli, sir, my function is not necessarily searches by **id**. But okay, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression this might be helpful

```
var result = myArray.filter(function(element, index) { return element.ID == 5; });
```

filter() has two parameters

element - current row

index - current row index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to stick with the array, the 'ugly' for loop is your best bet for compatibility. It's not that ugly when put in a function:

```
function findById(id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
        if(myArray[i].id === id) return myArray[i];
    }
}

// Not checking return value here!
alert(findById(5).name);
```

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is another option if your concern is only with recent versions of browsers.  It will return an array of values.

If your array is very large though, it would make sense to introduce some sort of index for efficient lookups.  It adds an additional maintenance burden, but can increase performance for frequent lookups:

```
var index = {};
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    index[myArray[i].id] = i;
}

// Find element with id=5
alert(myArray[index[5]].name);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmHm/)