# Return subset of object using jQuery CSV

Tags: jquery, object, subset, slice, jquery-csv

I'm using [jQuery CSV](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/) to parse a .csv file on my web server. I've got that working using a demo file with a list of countries with additional fields (Common Name, Capital, Country Code, etc.).

From there, I'm using a lookup function found here: [Jquery how to find an Object by attribute in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579678/jquery-how-to-find-an-object-by-attribute-in-an-array/19154349#19154349) to return matching objects from the parsed file.

Here is my code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){                         
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "path/countrylist.csv",
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(data) {
       var data = $.csv.toObjects(data);
       console.log(data);

       var country = lookup(data, "Common Name", "Albania");
       $.each(country, function(i, val) {
           $("#albania").append(i + ": " + val + "<br/>");
       });
     });
  });
```

This returns the 'Albania' object which I'm displaying in a div with id '#albania':

```
Sort Order: 2
Common Name: Albania
Formal Name: Republic of Albania
Type: Independent State
Sub Type: 
Sovereignty: 
Capital: Tirana
ISO 4217 Currency Code: ALL
ISO 4217 Currency Name: Lek
ITU-T Telephone Code: 355
ISO 3166-1 2 Letter Code: AL
ISO 3166-1 3 Letter Code: ALB
ISO 3166-1 Number: 8
IANA Country Code TLD: .al
```

Where I'm stuck is I want to display a subset of this data from the country object. For example, I only want to display the Common Name, Capital and Country Code.

Assuming that these keys/header rows are the same for each country, how can I show just those values? jQuery .slice() is not working, perhaps because this is an object and not an array(?).

Can I select the subset by key/header row name? That could be another option as those won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved. I needed to use $.each() and dot notation to target specific keys in the object.

Here is my working code that grabs only the Common Name and Capital, then appends that to a div with and id of the country name:

```
$.each( data, function( i, v ) {
var name = v.Common_Name.toLowerCase();
var country = v.Common_Name;
var capital = v.Capital;

    $("#" + name).append(
        "Name" + ": " + country + "<br/>" 
               + "Capital" + ": " + capital + "<br/>"
    );
});
```

My html:

```
<div class="countries clearfix">
    <div id="afghanistan" class="country"></div>
    <div id="albania" class="country"></div>
    <div id="algeria" class="country"></div>
    <div id="andorra" class="country"></div>
</div>
```

The result:

```
Name: Afghanistan
Capital: Kabul

Name: Albania
Capital: Tirana

Name: Algeria
Capital: Algiers

Name: Andorra
Capital: Andorra la Vella
```